# Custom UITableViewCell contentView height

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have custom `UITableViewCell`:

```
@interface PostCell ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet PostView *postView;

@end

@implementation PostCell

- (void)setPost:(Post *)newPost
{
    self.postView.post = newPost;
}

@end
```

which contains custom `PostView` (`UIView` subclass).

This is how I send `Post` `model` to `PostCell` which then forwards that `model` to `PostView` `subview` and `PostView` `subview` draws itself depending on contents of `Post` `model`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"PostCell";

    PostCell *postCell = (PostCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    Post *post = self.displayPosts[indexPath.row];
    [postCell setPost:post];

    return postCell;
}
```

I hope this is good approach, I referenced on some apples custom UITableView example for fast drawing.

Lets say that `Post` `model` have `title` and `image` properties. Since every PostView will be different `height` how could I calculate that `height` and return it to `heightForRowAtIndexPath`?

Would it be good to add this method in my custom `UITableView` cell:

```
- (CGFloat)heightForCell
{
    return self.postView.frame.size.height;
}
```

and then

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // here we will need custom height based on image and text
    PostCell *postCell = (PostCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    return [postCell heightForCell];
}
```

I have tried this but

```
PostCell *postCell = (PostCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

throws me exception.

First I would like to know if its good approach and if it is then I can go on with removing that exception break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your cell is not created yet when `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` is called (thats why you get the exception). The best approach is you add new property into your `Post` object call it `cellHeight`, and save the height of the cell in this object. Then return something like `post.cellHeight`

Comment: Ohh, so heightForRow is called before? Well that makes sense :D